# jQuery append() - looks to me like it should work but doesn't

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble appending a get() to a dynamically created div. I've marked with a comment the code that's giving me trouble. Can someone please take a look and see what's wrong with it?

```
var weekday = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
        today = new Date().getDay(),
        list = $('ul.yui-nav');

    for(var x=0;x<=6;x++){
        $('#' + weekday[x]).hide();
        list.append(
            $('<li></li>', {
                html : '<a href = "#' + weekday[x].toLowerCase() + '">' + weekday[x] + '</a>'
            }).toggleClass(function(){
                if(today == x){
                    return 'selected';
                }
            }).bind('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().children('li').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#' + weekday[x]).hide();
                $('#' + weekday[x]).show();
            })
        );



                    // the 5 lines below is where I'm having trouble
        $('div.yui-content').append(
            $('<div class="content" id="' + weekday[x] + '"></div>').append(
                $.get('index.php')
            )
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.get` returns a XHR object, not a string of HTML or a valid HTML element.

`$.get` is also asynchronous so you need to use it's callback to be able to use it's response from the server:

```
    //make AJAX call to `index.php`, storing the server-response in the `serverResponse` variable
    $.get('index.php', function (serverResponse) {

        //select the element to append-to
        $('div.yui-content').append(

            //create a new div and append the server-response to it
            $('<div class="content" id="' + weekday[x] + '"></div>').append(serverResponse));
    });
```

Since you are concocting a string of HTML anyway, you could just put the `serverResponse` directly into the creation of the `.content` div:

```
        $('div.yui-content').append(
            $('<div class="content" id="' + weekday[x] + '">' + serverResponse + '</div>'));
```

### Update

Since you are running this inside a loop you can use a closure to keep the value of `x` intact for the callback function:

```
(function(newX) {
    $.get('index.php', function (serverResponse) {
        $('div.yui-content').append(
            $('<div class="content" id="' + weekday[newX] + '"></div>').append(serverResponse));
    });
})(x);
```

This is necessary because when the callback function executes, the value of `x` in the scope of the loop will have changed. Using a closure we are basically creating a new scope (function) in which the value of `x` is "saved" (as `newX`) until it is needed (which could be anytime in the future).

Also, I would suggest buffering the HTML that you are appending to the DOM and adding it at once, rather than calling `.append()` each iteration of the loop:

```
 list = [];

    for(var x=0;x<=6;x++){
        $('#' + weekday[x]).hide();
        list.push(...
```

Then after your loop is done running:

```
for (...) {...}
$('ul.yui-nav').append(list.join(''));
```

Comment: You'll also need another function to retain the correct value of `x`, since this is being done in a loop.

Comment: @amnotiam Good catch, I didn't see that this was inside the loop.

Comment: Don't forget pass in `x` to your IIFE. Currently you're shadowing `x` with an undefined `x` parameter. ;)

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks again, I was looking at it thinking, "this isn't quite right," but I'm pretty new to the idea of IIFE so I was about to ask you that very question. Does that look about right now?

Comment: i actually wound up changing the code so that it's not in the loop, but this helped me get what I needed. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` does an `ajax` call which in `async` by nature and it returns an xhr object. So either execute your code inside `$.get`'s callback or you can use `load` method like this.

```
$('<div />', { 
      class: "content", 
      id: weekday[x] 
})
.appendTo('div.yui-content')
.load('index.php');
```

Note, I am using `appendTo` method to append the dynamically created `div.content` inside `div.yui-content`.

If you use `load` then you don't have to create closure because the `div` is already created before calling `load`.

- `load()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/
- `appendTo()`    reference: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/